# When can you "plug in" a function $g(x)$ directly into a taylor expansion of a function $f(x)$ to get the expansion of $f(g(x))$, specifics below

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

I have asked a couple of questions

[Representing $\ln(x)$ as a power series centered at $2$ without computing any derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843161/representing-lnx-as-a-power-series-centered-at-2-without-computing-any-de)

[Computing the taylor series of $f(x)=(x+2)^{1/2}$ around $x=2$ up to order 2 terms using binomial series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829261/computing-the-taylor-series-of-fx-x21-2-around-x-2-up-to-order-2-ter)

Where I was trying to compute a Taylor series for a function while avoiding computing derivatives. I am hoping mathstack can clear up some of my confusion more generally.

As an example, I just tried to compute the Taylor series of 
$$
e^{x^2-x}
$$
I am hoping to get some good guidelines (not necessarily rigorous, since "plugging in" isn't exactly a rigorous definition) for when you can just plug a function in to a Taylor expansion as follows 
$$
e^{x^2-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2-x)^k}{k!}=1+x^2+\frac{(x^2-x)}{2}+\frac{(x^2-x)^3}{6}+......
$$
I know it is correct to also think of the above expansion as the product of $e^{-x}$ and $e^{x^2}$, both of which are easy to expand and say convolve to get a specific degree coefficient, but is the above also fine?

My more general questions on problems of this type are:

1) 
Generally, what do I need to be aware of theoretically? Are there any theorems I am implicitly using in the above example, both when I plug in $x^2-x$ and when I take an infinite product? I think for the latter, I need both series to be absolutely convergent.

2)
For convergence, you obviously inherit the restrictions on $x$ for convergence when you modify a series to compute another Taylor expansion, like when you integrate $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ to compute $\arctan$'s expansion, you still have the restriction that $x^2<1$. But need those restrictions be as strict in the modified series as the original? In other words, am I losing some radius for $x$ by computing in this way? Can the restrictions sometimes get stricter depending on the operation you perform to modify the series?

Thanks

Comment: That expansion works just fine, but it's not a power series.

Comment: @zhw. Isn't it just a power series that isn't expanded?

Comment: That series equals a power series, but is not itself a power series.

Comment: Shouldn't the expansion be $1+(x^2-x)+\dfrac{(x^2-x)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(x^2-x)^3}{6}+\cdots$?